# Starting Dagger2, How to construct structure?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I am studying Dagger2 now. I am studying by looking at several examples. But there are some parts that aren't working properly, looking at the examples. I know that the structure of Dagger2 should be defined and implemented in the order of application -> active -> user component. However, an error occurred when following this. the message is `java.lang.RuntimeException: android.app.Application does not implement dagger.android.HasActivityInjector` 
The code is long, but I wish someone would show up to help me. I am very desperate.

**AppComponent**

```
@Singleton 
@Component(modules = [AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
                      ActivityBindingModule::class,
                      ApplicationModule::class]) 
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<BaseApplication> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder
        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

**BaseApplication**

```
class BaseApplication : DaggerApplication() {
     override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build()
    }
}
```

**ActivityScope**

```
@Scope
annotation class ActivityScope
```

**ActivityBindingModule**

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBindingModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MainModule::class])
    abstract fun mainActivity(): MainActivity

}
```

**MainModule**

```
@Module
class MainModule {
    @ActivityScope
    @Provides
    fun util() : Utils = Utils()

}
```

**ApplicationModule**

```
@Module
class ApplicationModule {
    @Provides
    fun providesContext(application: Application): Context {
        return application
    }
}
```

**Utils**

```
class Utils {
    @Inject constructor(){
    }
    fun add(a :Int, b:Int):Int= a+b
    fun sub(a :Int, b:Int):Int= a-b
    fun div(a :Int, b:Int):Int= a/b
    fun mul(a :Int, b:Int):Int= a*b

}
```

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity(), HasActivityInjector {

    lateinit var utils : Utils

    @Inject
    lateinit var activityDispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var aa = utils.add(10,20)

        Log.d("TAG",""+aa)

    }

    override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity> {
        return activityDispatchingAndroidInjector
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you forgot the `android:name` for the `<application` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: when I edit the android:name .MainActivity to .BaseApplication, there is only recommandation about ".MainActivity"

Comment: That's because you're editing the name of an `<activity` and not for the `<application`.

Answer (score 0):

Make application class implement HasActivityInjector

class UserApplication extends Application implements HasActivityInjector{
}

Answer (score 0):

I able to solved this problem by adding `android:name=".BaseApplication"` at AndroidManifest.xml

> ```
> <application
>     android:name=".BaseApplication"
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
>     android:supportsRtl="true"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
>     <activity android:name=".AuthActivity">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
> </application>
> ```